# Store a generated random number in a variable, then call that variable as a filename to bring up an image. Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, random

So I have a few pictures that I want to randomly generate on a page.
the pictures are named 0 - 9 .png
Im using a premade function for random number generation.
My problem is when I try to call on this function later down the page, it doesnt place the images. Nothing appears.

I know this is simple but Im beating my head on my desk over here.
What I want to know is what messed up with my function?

```
function showimg()  
{  
    /*  
    The showimg() function displays a random image from the 0.png through 9.png
    files.  
    */  
    var imgNumber = randomInteger(9);  
    return imgNumber;  
    /* Return a random number from 0 to 9 */  
    document.write("<img src='imgNumber.png' alt='' />");  

}
```

Comment: Why do you have `document.write("");`? Do you know what that does?

Comment: I have document.write because I want to be able to call on the function and have it automatically put the html in the document where I've called the function

Comment: Ok, I would suggest putting an image tag in the html where you want the image, and then update the source.  document.write will replace everything on the page with whatever argument you pass.

Comment: @Dlorwisdom whoa, `document.write` is not going to "automatically put the html in the document where I've called it". It will do what NaNpx said, overwrite your whole document.

Comment: How would I insert a javascript function inside of an img tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with how you're approaching this problem.

First, it is bad practice in modern Javascript development to use `document.write`. You should be using things like `appendChild` instead.

Second, you reference `imgNumber` in a string. This will just use "imgNumber" there, not the contents of the `imgNumber` variable. For that, string concatenation is one way you could insert it:

```
"<img src='" + imgNumber + ".png'>"
```

Here's how I would approach your problem instead. First, place an empty element on the page where you will append your images:

```
<div id="random-images-here"></div>
```

Then, somewhere after that element you can have the following Javascript, which is similar to yours:

```
<script>
    // create a random integer from 0 to maxInt
    var randomInteger = function(maxInt) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxInt + 1));
    };

    // append a random image to el
    var showImg = function(el) {
        var imgNumber = randomInteger(9),
            img = document.createElement('img');

        img.src = imgNumber + ".png";
        img.alt = "Image #" + imgNumber;

        el.appendChild(img);
    };

    // grab the element to append images to
    var imgHolder = document.getElementById('random-images-here');

    // place 4 images in the image holder
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        showImg(imgHolder);
    }
</script>
```

### [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YAmmB/)

(Note: I changed the code in the demo slightly to use a site I found with number images.)

Comment: Thank you so much mVChr! taking a look at your code and comparing it to mine really helped me figure this out. I know you said the way I was going about this is bad practice, but I am doing this for a class, and I had to follow certain guidelines. Either way, thanks a lot. I got it up and running and I can finally submit it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to say `document.write("<img src='" + imgNumber + ".png' alt='' />");`.  Even though imgNumber is an integer, JavaScript will automatically cast it to a string.

Also, you need to put the `document.write` call before the `return` statement.

However, like these other people are saying, `document.write` is probably not the best way to add things to your page.  I would recommend getting JQuery or something, and using that for your DOM manipulation.

Comment: Thanks! The way the tutorial in my book presented it, made it sound like I needed to put the document.write last. It still isnt bringing up the pictures though?

Comment: If it's still not bringing up the pictures, you can A) inspect the DOM and make sure the IMG tags are being added, B) open up your JavaScript console in your browser to see if there are any errors, and C) point your browser directly to the URLs of the images and make sure they are indeed there.  Hopefully that helps.  Good luck with this

Answer (score 0):

you are writing javascript so you need to edit the source of the image it would work if you are try it in php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Example</title>
<script>
        var imgNumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*9)+1);

 document.getElementById("example").src= imgNumber + '.png';


</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id='example' src="" alt="">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: javascript can be called to return you a value but on an event listener not on src so if you want it to give you a random number and show you a random image so you would need to ask the javascript to edit the src of the image with the random number function just generated try above solution it will work out fine

Answer (score -1):

document.write is after the return. Its unreachable code.