# Saving image as jpg in php issue

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Having code to display image like:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="aaa.jpg"');

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $row['pageurl'];
}
else
{
echo mysql_error();
}
```

Problem,is every time it saves images as aaa.jpg(name i have given),now i want to save with different name each time as 1111.jpg gdfgfdg.jpg or randomly.How to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20108850/1862107 here the same

Comment: Are you looking for an answer other than "change the file name you've put in your code?"

Comment: yes,whenever we save img in browser by 'save as' it now naming file as aaa.jpg,i want to rename randomly everytime user save img